# Find all text boxes in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to implement Expand or Collapse facility to my report in **SQLSERVER 2008R2.**

For that purpose I have taken a text box named `TextBox16`.

But when I went to Tablix property and then visibility and then hide and Display can be toggled by this report item. Here I am not able to see all text boxes it showing to me, only odd number text boxes. Then how can I find all text boxes from Tablix property?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need all text boxes in this dropdown? Is the textbox you want to use in a parent group of the group on which you want to change visibility?

Answer (score 0):

How to see all text boxes:

Click on the body of the report.
Hit F4.
Under the properties title is a drop down with every single object in your report.  All of your text boxes should be listed in here.